# Linq group by only with max value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

I have the following case:
One table Employee, like:

```
----------
Id, Name, ....
----------
```

and other table with information about employees, that are new for each day, like:

```
EmployeeInfo
----------
EmployeeId, Date, someinfo
----------
```

All this is mapped on entity framework.
One example would be:

```
Employee:
----------
id        Name
----------
1         Ep1
----------
2         Ep2
----------
EmployeeInfo
----------
EmployeeId     Date           someinfo
----------------------------------------
01            06/28/17        Infox
----------------------------------------
01            05/28/17        Infoy
----------------------------------------
02            05/27/17        Infog
----------------------------------------
02            05/25/17        Infoh
----------------------------------------
```

I want to query this data using linq. My goal is to search the employee and the most recent info from EmployeeInfo.
My strategy was use groupby and max to search all employeeInfo and retrieve a structure like:

> `IGrouping <string, EmployeeInfo>`
>   Example of return data:

```
<"01", EmployeeInfo>
<"02", EmployeeInfo>
```

where EmployeeInfo contais the last data for each employee

The only solution was using select new and making max like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086118/4580924

Is there a solution for this that differs from link above?

Comment: The solution at the link does not give you what you need, though: it gives you the latest date, rather than the info on the latest date.

Comment: Please provide your table definitions as legal C# code, along with suitable sample data (again in C# code), and what you expect the output to look like. Then we can answer easily. Right now it is too much hard work for us. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the record where some attribute is max, rather than the value of that max attribute itself, use `OrderBy` followed by `First`, like this:

```
from e in Employee
join ei in EmployeeInfo on e.EmployeeId equals ei.EmployeeId
group e by e.EmployeeId into g
select g.OrderByDescending(ge => ge.Date).First()
```

Comment: it was the exact solution