# C# LINQ How to get max value

Tags: c#, linq, max

Having a list with data like:

```
{ surname = surname_1, title = title_4, release_number = 111, year = 2021 }
{ surname = surname_1, title = title_1, release_number = 111, year = 2020 }
{ surname = surname_2, title = title_5, release_number = 222, year = 2021 }
{ surname = surname_2, title = title_2, release_number = 222, year = 2020 }
{ surname = surname_3, title = title_8, release_number = 222, year = 2022 }
```

How can I get **max** year for each `release_number`:

```
{ReleaseNumber = 111, Year = 2021}
{ReleaseNumber = 222, Year = 2022}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ GROUP BY and MAX()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085947/linq-group-by-and-max)

Comment: You should read [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) or book for C#, for example [C# in a nutshell](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-90-in/9781098100957/)

Comment: What you posted isn't data. It's certainly not valid C# or even JSON. What does your actual *code* look like? Have you tried using `GroupBy` or `Max` ?

Comment: @JoshMein that's not a good duplicate. That question is far more complicated and specific to EF. A developer that would understand what parts are relevant wouldn't be asking about Group By and Max in the first place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah I realized that after the fact, but this is still a duplicate and little effort has been shown in trying to solve the problem. I am searching for another duplicate now.

Comment: This question looks similar [How do I get the MAX row with a GROUP BY in LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the MAX row with a GROUP BY in LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have a `list` of items you could have this LINQ query:

```
var releaseGroups = 
    from item in list
    group item by item.release_number into releaseGroup
    select new {ReleaseNumber = releaseGroup.Key, MaxYear = realseGroup.Select(o=>o.year).Max()};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model for your data then use code below

```cs
var items= new List<YourModel> {
    new YourModel { surname = surname_1, title = title_4, release_number = 111, year = 2021 },
    new YourModel { surname = surname_1, title = title_1, release_number = 111, year = 2020 },
    new YourModel { surname = surname_2, title = title_5, release_number = 222, year = 2021 },
    new YourModel { surname = surname_3, title = title_8, release_number = 222, year = 2022 },
};

var MaxByYear=
    from item in items
    group item by item.year into itemGroup
    select new
    {
        Year = itemGroup.Key,
        Max= itemGroup.Max(x => x.release_number),
    };
```

// MaxByYear is collection of anonymous objects:

Answer (score 0):

LINQ syntax is roughly equivalent to SQL. To get a maximum value in a specific grouping in SQL you use the GROUP BY clause to specify the grouping, then select the maximum value in that group.

```
SELECT Key,MAX(SomeField)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY Key
```

All other answers show how to do this, eg :

```
list
  .GroupBy(i => i.release_number)
  .Select(grp => new {grp.Key, grp.Select(i => i.year).Max());
```

When working with an in memory list though, `GroupBy` has [several overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-4(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-2))-system-func((-1-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-2))-3)))) that can shorten the code to a single line :

```
var results=list.GroupBy(item => item.release_number,
                         item=>item.Year,
                         (key,values) => new { 
                                           Key=key,
                                           Max=values.Max()
            });
```

In [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-4(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-2))-system-func((-1-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-2))-3)))), the first argument extracts the group key. The second extracts the values we want in that group. The final argument calculates the result for each key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your data by release number and then take max year (or order by descending year and take first).

```
var res = testData.GroupBy(x => x.ReleaseNumber)
                .Select(x => new {ReleaseNumber = x.Key, Year = x.OrderByDescending(t => t.Year).First().Year});
```

Here my full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<TestData> testData = new List<TestData>()
            {
                new TestData() {ReleaseNumber = 111, Year = 2021},
                new TestData() {ReleaseNumber = 111, Year = 2020},
                new TestData() {ReleaseNumber = 222, Year = 2021},
                new TestData() {ReleaseNumber = 222, Year = 2020},
                new TestData() {ReleaseNumber = 222, Year = 2022},
            };

            var res = testData
                .GroupBy(x => x.ReleaseNumber)
                .Select(x => new {ReleaseNumber = x.Key, Year = x.OrderByDescending(t => t.Year).First().Year});

            foreach (var r in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Release number: {r.ReleaseNumber}, Year: {r.Year}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class TestData
    {
        public int ReleaseNumber { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list
  .GroupBy(i => i.release_number)
  .Select(grp => new {grp.Key, grp.Select(i => i.year).Max()});
```

Comment: There is a missing closing bracket in your answer.